# Export Recordset to Excel

Tags: vb6, export-to-excel, adodb, recordset

I am trying to export a Adodb Recordset to excell through a VB 6.0 application. I can do that by For Loop. But the recordset contains 100 columns with 200000 Rows. So it is consuming huge time to complete the tusk.At times it is getting hanged.
 Is there a fast way to achieve the same?
Thankx in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to dramatically improve the performance of ADODB.Recordset objects.  One of the best tips I've used to speed things up is to create explicit [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects in your loop:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fldLastName As ADODB.Field, fldFirstName As ADODB.Field

rs.Open "SELECT au_lname, au_fname FROM authors", "DSN=pubs", , , adCmdText

Set fldLastName = rs.Fields("au_lname")
Set fldFirstName = rs.Fields("au_fname")

Do Until rs.EOF
    csvOutput = csvOutput & fldLastName & "," & fldFirstName & vbCrLf
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

This can really speed things up because you avoid late binding in referring to the Recordset.Field.Value items.  Give it a try and you should see a huge improvement in performance.  I have worked with large recordsets like the one you described and the performance has been made tolerable using this technique.

By the way, there is a good article on MSDN that has some other tips that might help improve the performance of your ADODB code here - [ADO Performance Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496013%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).  The article is quite old now but I think it all still applies after reading it again for the first time in years.

Comment: Why do you think your loop, which involves making a 'deep copy' of `csvOutput` 200K times, will perform better than simply calling the Recordset object's `GetString` method e.g. `csvOutput = rs.GetString(,,",",vbCrLf)` means only one assignment to `csvOutput` rather than 200K.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

The Excel object model has a `CopyFromRecordset` method.

The Recordset object has a `GetRows` method to return an array which you can 'transpose' into an Excel `Range` object's `Value` property ('transpose' = columns to rows and vice versa -- Excel has a `Transpose` worksheet function that can be invoked via its object model).

Note that before Excel 2007, worksheets were limited to 65,536 rows and you may find that the abovementioned Excel methods are similarly limited.

The Recordset object has a `GetString` method to write all rows at once to a string (no need to loop).

You may be able bypass the recordset completely and use Access SQL (ACE, Jet, whatever) to write the data directly to Excel e.g.

```
SELECT *
  INTO [Excel 8.0;DATABASE=C:\MyNewWorkbook.xls].MyNewTable 
  FROM [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;UID=Admin;PWD=***].MyDBTable;
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  I have always used the loop technique and been pretty happy with that but the options you present look even better.